# What does "Unabomber types" mean?

Tags: meaning

In heist-comedy movie, *Logan Lucky (2017)*, Purple Lady is getting her hair care from Millie, then
Jimmy arrived for Millie:

> Purple Lady: You should pay your bills. Everyone  needs a cell phone.
>
> Jimmy: But I don't like 'em.
>
> Purple Lady: You one of them **Unabomber types**?

What does "Unabomber types" mean?

Comment: What part of the phrase is confusing you?  Did you look up [Unabomber](https://www.history.com/topics/crime/unabomber-ted-kaczynski)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Unabomber was a domestic terrorist who killed or tried to kill people who were involved in technology or were deemed to be hostile to the natural environment.